# Set current item in a HTML <select>, but in the middle

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

This works to set a specific `<option>` as the currently selected item in a `<select>`:

[image]

```js
var l = document.getElementById("list");
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    l.innerHTML += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
l.value = 17;
```

```css
#list { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<select id="list" multiple size=10>
</select>
```

But the item is selected *at the end*, which is not always the desired UI/UX.

Question: **How to make that the selected item appears in the middle of the listview, or, alternatively, on top of the listview?**

(if possible of course, e.g. if there are enough subsequent items).

Comment: How do you envision this looking if there are multiple items selected?

Comment: @mykaf: the first selected item appears in the middle of the listview (or alternatively, on top of the listview).

Comment: old school days solution was to set value down the list.... `l.value = 17 + 5; setTimeout(() => l.value = 17, 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the [selected `<option>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript).

---

The `block` parameter controls the vertical alignment:

Valid values: `start`, `center`, `end`, and `nearest`. Defaults to `nearest`.

---

Demo, press the button to call `scrollIntoView()`

```js
var l = document.getElementById("list");
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    l.innerHTML += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
}
l.value = 17;

// Demo
const selected = l.options[l.selectedIndex];
const intoView = (block = 'center') => selected.scrollIntoView({ block });
intoView();
```

```css
#list { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<select id="list" multiple size=10></select>

<!--  DEMO -->
<br />
<button onclick='intoView("start");'>Start</button>
<button onclick='intoView();'>Center</button>
<button onclick='intoView("nearest");'>Nearest</button>
<button onclick='intoView("end");'>End</button>
<!-- /DEMO -->
```

Comment: Perfect, wonderful !

Comment: Great, but I have a lot of question about your answer.
I posted it as another question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76050037/how-to-scroll-options-in-a-select-list-question-about-an-answer